# I created this program, but its giving output "segmentation error (core dumped)" , what do I do?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I created this program for assignment. Compiler complies it but when I run to check the output, it gives the following error:  
 
[image]

 
The code is given below:

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    private:
        int testscore;
        int intmarks;
        char * name;
        Node * nextnode;
    public:
        void settestscore (int testscore) { this -> testscore = testscore; }
        int gettestscore () { return testscore; }
        void setintmarks (int intmarks) { this -> intmarks = intmarks; }
        int getintmarks () { return intmarks; }
        void setname (char * name) { this -> name = name; }
        char * getname () { return name; }
        void setnext (Node * nextnode) { this -> nextnode = nextnode; }
        Node * getnext () { return nextnode; }
};

class List {
    private:
        int size;
        Node * headnode;
        Node * currentnode;
        Node * lastcurrentnode;
    public:
        friend void printlist(List list);
        friend List addcandidates();
        List() {
            headnode = new Node();
            currentnode -> setnext(NULL);
            currentnode = NULL;
            lastcurrentnode = NULL;
            size = 0;
        }
        void addnode(int score, int marks, char * name) {
            Node * newnode = new Node();
            newnode -> settestscore (score);
            newnode -> setintmarks (marks);
            newnode -> setname (name);
            if (currentnode != NULL) {
                newnode -> setnext (currentnode -> getnext());
                currentnode -> setnext (newnode);
                lastcurrentnode = currentnode;
                currentnode = newnode;
            }
            else {
                newnode -> setnext (NULL);
                currentnode -> setnext (newnode);
                lastcurrentnode = headnode;
                currentnode = newnode;
            }
        }
        int gettestscore () {
            if (currentnode != NULL)
                return currentnode->gettestscore();
        }
        int getintmarks () {
            if (currentnode != NULL)
                return currentnode->getintmarks();
        }
        char * getname () {
            if (currentnode != NULL)
                return currentnode->getname();
        }
        bool next() {
            if (currentnode == NULL) {
                return false;
            }
            lastcurrentnode = currentnode;
            currentnode = currentnode -> getnext();
            if (currentnode == NULL || size == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }

};

List addcandidates() {
    List list;
    list.addnode(50, 20, "Annie Khalid");
    list.addnode(35, 30, "Humaira Arshad");
    list.addnode(37, 29, "Atif Aslam");
    list.addnode(59, 10, "Qurat-ul-Ain Baloch");
    list.addnode(25, 9, "Sanam Marvi");
    list.addnode(44, 11, "Ali Zafar");
    list.addnode(59, 16, "Farhan Saeed");
    list.addnode(50, 22, "Amanat Ali");
    list.addnode(60, 28, "Junaid Jamshed");
    list.addnode(78, 17, "Shahzad Roy");
    list.addnode(78, 15, "Ali Azmat");
    list.addnode(40, 30, "Nadeem Abbas");
    return list;
}

void printlist(List list) {
    Node * tempnode = list.currentnode;
    list.currentnode = list.headnode;
    for (int i = 1; list.next(); i++) {
    cout << i << ": " << list.getname() << "\t \t" << list.gettestscore() << "\t \t" << list.getintmarks() ;
    }
    list.currentnode = tempnode;
}

main() {
    List list = addcandidates();
    printlist(list);
}
```

I couldn't find where the problem is? I need some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would run to the hills with a wet flannel over my face - or use a debugger to narrow it down

Comment: _"What do I do"_ Most probably dereferencing some dangling or incorrectly initialized pointer. Use a debugger and step through your code to find out about the details.

Comment: @EdHeal Do you still have close votes today? Give 'em one ...

Comment: You want help w/ a program you neither describe, comment *at all*, nor give any info about the problem other than it crashes somewhere doing something.  Good luck with that.

Comment: Do not leave the homework to the last minute

Comment: What does `currentnode` point at when you do `currentnode -> setnext(NULL);`?

Comment: hmm... But I was busy in other assignments too, I have exams in next month :( @EdHeal

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Do not tell my boyfriend to give him one - Guess the breakfast will be burnt despite it being cornflakes

Comment: it points to `Node * currentnode; ` in the `private` of `List` class... @molbdnilo

Comment: @Jack - I have to do a delivery as well.

Comment: You can ask your boyfriend to deliver on your behalf, but I don't have any boyfriend :P @EdHeal

Comment: @EdHeal It's spoiled already, I wanted to have _"crunchy nuts"_ :( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Not the usual salty ones?

Comment: @Jack No, `currentnode` is a pointer to a `Node`. It does not point to itself. (What the name "currentnode" refers to, and what the value of the variable with that name is, is a crucial distinction to make.) You need to figure out *which* `Node`, if any, it points to when you execute that line.

Comment: @EdHeal _"Not the usual salty ones?"_ Sugar and nuts are essential, choc shock optional :P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I am going to be crude - Well sometimes you can floss with the public hair The cheese is not that good,

Comment: @EdHeal I don't think we _really_ disagree, how to handle this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in your constructor of `List`:

```
List() {
    headnode = new Node();
    currentnode->setnext(NULL); // <--- error is here!
    currentnode = NULL;
    lastcurrentnode = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
```

At this point your pointer `currentnode` is NULL (and you are setting it to NULL afterwards also, which makes no sense). You'd first have to create a new `Node` and assign it to `currentnode` for it to work, just like you did with `headnode`, or assign `headnode` to `currentnode` directly (as it seems that you use `currentnode` for iterating, that would set things up "correctly" during construction).

When you are dereferencing (calling `setnext()`) your `currentNode` while it is NULL your program crashes.

There are a lot other things going on in your code, you should really revise it throroughly and get into a few tutorials on pointer-semantics. But just answering your question, the marked line is your problem.

Also, running this with a debugger and stepping trough your code is very simple and makes you find these kind of error with ease :)

EDIT, Just as a heads-up: Even when you fix this problem, you are not going to get the list printed. Your managing of `currentnode` and `headnode` is not correct, so you'll get a wrong linked list, and after correcting that, your printing is also buggy. Sorry to break the news...

Comment: hmm... gonna write it again, will show the final output.